# SQL query to select all rows with max column value

Tags: mysql, sql

```
CREATE TABLE `user_activity` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `user_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `type` enum('request','response') DEFAULT NULL,
  `data` longtext NOT NULL,
  `created_at` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  `source` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  `task_name` varchar(255) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);
```

I have this data:-

[image]

Now I need to select all rows for `user_id=527` where `created_at` value is the maximum. So I need the last 3 rows in this image.

I wrote this query:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM   user_activity 
WHERE  user_id = 527 
       AND source = 'E1' 
       AND task_name IN ( 'GetReportTask', 'StopMonitoringUserTask' ) 
       AND created_at = (SELECT Max(created_at) 
                         FROM   user_activity 
                         WHERE  user_id = 527 
                                AND source = 'E1' 
                                AND task_name IN ( 'GetReportTask', 
                                                   'StopMonitoringUserTask' ));
```

This is very inefficient because I am running the exact same query again as an inner query except that it disregards `created_at`. What's the right way to do this?

Comment: Assuming you will use this for more than one user_id, you can create a subquery, view, temp table, etc. that captures Max(created_at), user_id, source, task_name and GROUP BY everything but Max(created_at).  Then you have the max date for lots of conditions.  Then join on multiple fields, i.e. the user_id, the source, the task_name.

Comment: there has to be a better way to write this query.. using a self-join or something

Comment: Do you ever want to select *all* (or many) users in one query, or is it always a single user_id per query?

Comment: @Bohemian single user always

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used [EverSQL](https://www.eversql.com/sql-query-optimizer/) and applied my own changes to come up with this single-select query that uses self-join:-

```
SELECT * 
FROM   user_activity AS ua1 
       LEFT JOIN user_activity AS ua2 
              ON ua2.user_id = ua1.user_id 
                 AND ua2.source = ua1.source 
                 AND ua2.task_name IN ( 'GetReportTask', 'StopMonitoringUserTask' ) 
                 AND ua1.created_at < ua2.created_at 
WHERE  ua1.user_id = 527 
       AND ua1.source = 'E1' 
       AND ua1.task_name IN ( 'GetReportTask', 'StopMonitoringUserTask' ) 
       AND ua2.created_at IS NULL;
```

However, I noticed that the response times of both queries were similar. I tried to use [Explain](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/explain.html) to identify any performance differences; and from what I understood from its output, there are no noticeable differences because proper indexing is in place. So for readability and maintainability, I'll just use the nested query.

Answer (score 1):

I would use a correlated subquery:

```
SELECT ua.* 
FROM user_activity ua
WHERE ua.user_id = 527 AND source = 'E1' AND
      ua.task_name IN ('GetReportTask', 'StopMonitoringUserTask' ) AND
      ua.created_at = (SELECT MAX(ua2.created_at) 
                       FROM user_activity ua2
                       WHERE ua2.user_id = ua.user_id AND 
                             ua2.source = ua.source AND
                             ua2.task_name IN ( 'GetReportTask', 'StopMonitoringUserTask' )
                      );
```

Although this might seem inefficient, you can create an index on `user_activity(user_id, source, task_name, created_at)`.  With this index, the query should have decent performance.

Comment: Thanks, did you do this correlation just so I have to put `user_id` and `source` values once instead of twice as in my query, or does it give some performance improvements as well? I already have indexing in place & am sure the query won't be too slow.. just want to see if there is a better/faster way in which I don't have to run 2 select queries on the table.. may be using a self join or something?

Comment: @Kartik . . . It does simplify the query writing.  A correlated subquery will also use the index -- the optimizer might miss that with an uncorrelated subquery.

Answer (score 0):

Order by created_at desc and limit your query to return 1 row.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   user_activity 
WHERE  user_id = 527 
   AND source = 'E1' 
   AND task_name IN ( 'GetReportTask', 'StopMonitoringUserTask' ) 
ORDER BY created_at DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: this will just return 1 row.. I want **all** rows with max value.. please see the created_at values in the image of data

Comment: In that case select the latest timestamp into a variable to be used in the second query or created a stored procedure - there is no need to nest the queries to query single date field